# Session preview and staging site in one application

Tags: 2011, experience-manager, session-preview

I'm setting up a staging site in Websphere to work with experience manager.

Do I need to have the Session Preview webservice in a separate application to the staging site, or can they both be in the same application?

This is for Tridion 2011SP1 with HR2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have both in the same application. However you will need to configure both the CD Web Service (including session preview settings) and the application (including session preview settings).

You can find all of it documented here: [Adding the Experience Manager Web site extension to a JSP Web site](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/task_845BA8E057A645F1B7AF3ACBB3B73E72).

Answer (score 3):

Though it *might* work, it was designed (and tested) to be used with separate webapps.

The only worry I have is in the storage config, not 100% sure how the system will cope with it.